# Unhandled fault: imprecise external abort (0x1406) at 0x06e38067

Tags: linux, usb

Our platform has two one USB A ports and one USB OTG port. If we connect any one of the USB A port to the USB OTG port and then do a hard power reset (plug out and then plug in the power supply), the system does not boot and we get a kernel crash.

```
[    0.945983] Unhandled fault: imprecise external abort (0x1406) at 0x06e38067
[    0.946014] Internal error: : 1406 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[    0.946014] Modules linked in:
[    0.946044] CPU: 1    Not tainted  (3.0.31-00003-OMAP-Android #2)
[    0.946044] PC is at omap_rev+0x0/0x1c
[    0.946075] LR is at omap4430_phy_power+0x7c/0x10c
[    0.946075] pc : [<c0062c70>]    lr : [<c0080c9c>]    psr: 20000013
[    0.946105] sp : d784fed8  ip 84fef4
[    0.946105] r10: d7945005  r9 : d78fb200  r8 : c039aef8
[    0.946105] r7 : 00000000  r6 : 00000000  r5 : 00000000  r4 : c0859220
[    0.946105] r3 : fc0ab000  r2 : 00001800  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 00000000
[    0.94610c5387d  Table: 8000404a  DAC: 00000015
[    0.946136] 
[    0.946166] PC: 0xc0062bf0:
[    0.946166] 2bf0  089da830 e5943008 e5945010 e3530000 ba000015 e5940020 e5900
[    0.946166] 2c10  0a000003 e5940024 e1a01005 e12fff33 e89da830 e1a00005 eb020
[    0.946166] 2c30  089da830 e590300c e3530000 089da830 e593402c e3540000 089d5
[    0.946228] 2c50  eb023c62 e12fff34 e89da830 e30f0f60 e3a0109d e34c0073 eb010
[    0.946258] 2c70  e1a0c00d e92dd800 e24cb004 e3083708 e34c3085 e5930000 e89dd
[    0.946258] 2c90  e92dd800 e24cb004 e24dd008 e308c708 e34cc085 b0  e1100003 4
[    0.946289] 2cd0  e3083708 e34c3085 e5d32000 e593300c e3520044 0a000008 e5930
[    0.946319] 
[    0.946319] LR: 0xc0080c1c:
[    0.946319] 0c1c  e89da818 e1a0c00d e92dd878 e24cb004 e3520000 e1a05001 1a000
[    0.946319] 0c3c  e34c2085 e3a0c018 e3a00000 e5923000 e583c33c e89da878 e3095
[    0.946380] 0c5c  e5943010 e2831a02 e283ed83 e283cd82 e5916018 e386000f e5814
[    0.946411] 0c7c  e3826906 e58e6014 e59c1000 e3c10b0e e3802b06 e58c2000 e59c4
[    0.946411] 0c9c  e3003443 e1530a20 0a000015 ebff87f0 e3001446 e1510a20 0a00c
[    0.946441] 0cbc  e3003447 e1530a20 0a000006 e5941000 e3550000 c  eafffff1 e2
[    0.946502] 
[    0.946502] SP: 0xd784fe58:
[    0.946502] fe58  d784feac d784fe68 c0095554 c0093570 1253b94f 00000000 ffff4
[    0.946533] fe78  00000000 00000000 d784fef4 d784fe90 c005396c c004d53c 00000
[    0.946533] fe98  00001800 fc0ab000 c0859220 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0390
[    0.946563] feb8  d7945005 d784fef4 fc0ad080 d784fed8 c0080c9c 00000001 d784c
[    0.946594] fef8  d784ff24 d784ff08 c039b12c c039b6bc 00000001 d78063c0 c0a50
[    0.946624] ff18  d784ff5c d784ff28 c00baa14 c039af04 c061eb34 c0280500 d7800
[    0.946624] ff38  c0a5cdc0 c07fa590 c0a5cdd4 d78063d0 00000089 d784e000 d7840
[    0.946655] 
[    0.946655] IP: 0xfc0ad000:
[    0.946655] d000  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.946685] d020  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.946685] d040  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.946716] d060  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.946746] d080  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.946746] d0a0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.946777] d0c0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  00000000 0000
[    0.946807] 
[    0.946807] FP: 0xd784fe74:
[    0.946807] fe74  d784fec4 00000000 00000000 d784fef4 d784fe90 c005396c c0040
[    0.946838] fe94  00000000 00001800 fc0ab000 c0859220 00000000 00000000 00008
[    0.946868] feb4  d78fb200 d7945005 d784fef4 fc0ad080 d784fed8 c0080c9c c0063
[    0.946868] fed4  ffffffff c0080c20 d781b000 c081ae10 00000001 d784ff04 d7848
[    0.946899] fef4  c0080c2c d784ff24 d784ff08 c039b12c c039b6bc 00000001 d7800
[    0.946899] ff14  d7945000 d784ff5c d784ff28 c00baa14 c039af04 c061eb34 c0280
[    0.946929] ff34  d78063c0 c0a5cdc0 c07fa590 c0a5cdd4 d78063d0 00000089 d784c
[    0.946960] ff54  d784ff60 c00bb0b8 c00ba90c c004c4c0 c004b0a4 000 00000000 0
[    0.947052] b000  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947082] b020  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947082] b040  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947113] b060  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947113] 
[    0.947113] R4: 0xc08591a0:
[    0.947143] 91a0  ffffffff c08591a4 c08591a4 00000000 00000000 c085918c 00000
[ 000 00000000 00000000
[    0.947204] 9200  d7bfd000 d78b5480 d7896d00 000000fe d78bbf00 00000000 00008
[    0.947235] 9220  fc002000 c080f5e0 c080f57c c081083c fc0ab000 0000000 000004
[    0.947265] 9280  00000001 00000001 00000001 c0859248 c0859294 00000001 00001
[    0.947296] 
[    0.947296] R8: 0xc039ae78:
[    0.947296] ae78  e1a0c00d e92dd830 e24cb004 e3043cd4 e34c30a6 e1a05000 e1a04
[    0.947326] ae98  e3500000 03a00010 0a000004 e3a01020 ebf63a20 e3500000 03080
[    0.947357] aeb8  e2455f89 e1a0c000 e5804010 e1a01000 e5805014 e3a0ec03 e30a4
[    0.947357] aed8  e34c2039 e580c008 e580200c e580c004 e5950208 ebf48aee e3a00
[    0.947387] aef8  e1a0c00d e92dd878 e24cb004 e5904014 e5906010 e5941234 e5918
[    0.947387] af18  ebf63811 e3560003 979ff106 ea000034 c039af38 c039b0a0 c0390
[    0.947418] af38  e5d42eec e2126001 17c0201f 15c42eec 189da878 e5940234 e3a0f
[    0.947448] af58  e5d5c000 e35c0001 1a000008 e1a00004 e1a01006 ebfffe91 e594c
[    0.947448] 
[    0.947448] R9: 0xd78fb180:
[    0.947479] b180  73627573 65747379 3a87006d 766b538a 33937309 3369531f 33873
[  7270722d 312e636f 33287300 739b410a 3f28c11b 3a9f714a 7308f303
[    0.947509] b1e0  65776f70 b7690072 7ab77529 3eb8f097 7ed671e8 3ed85107 1e32f
[    0.947540] b200  d78fb220 d78fb204 d78fb204 c039aef8 00000001 d781b000 3e375
[    0.947570] b220  d78fb240 3e6851d3 1897e162 3068510b 5e974168 6a69c19f 34d76
[    0.947570] b240  d78fb260 3768c107 be970368 b068c597 fe854068 7e69c11a ee177
[    0.947601] b260  d78fb280 3e78c197 3ed76149 3e89c197 9e9f436b 3e684997 3e337
[    0.947601] 
[    0.947631] R10: 0xd7944f85:
[    0.947631] 40 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0305324 00000002 d78bedc0 00000000
[    0.947631] 4fa4  00000000 6963686f 616d6f2d 00003370 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947662] 4fc4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947692] 4fe4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947692] 5004  d78cae80 00000000 ffffffff 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947723] 5024  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947723] 5044  00000000 00000000 00000001 00000001 d7945054 0000 000000000
[    0.947784] 5084  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000
[    0.947784] Process kworker/u:0 (pid: 5, stack limit = 0xd784e2f8)
[    0.947814] Stack: (0xd784fed8 to 0xd7850000)
[    0.947814] fec0:                                                       c0080
[    0.947845] fee0: c081ae10 00000001 d784ff04 d784fef8 c039b6e8 00: c039b12c 8
[    0.947845] ff20: c00baa14 c039af04 c061eb34 c0280500 d78063c0 d78063c0 c0a50
[    0.947875] ff40: c0a5cdd4 d78063d0 00000089 d784e000 d784ffac d784ff60 c00bc
[    0.947875] ff60: c004c4c0 c004b0a4 c004ca00 c004ca00 c004ca00 d78063d0 c0040
[    0.947906] ff80: c00baf10 d7841ec4 00000002 d78063c0 c00baf10 00000000 00000
[    0.947906] ffa0: d784fff4 d784ffb0 c00c1cf4 c00baf1c 00000000 d78063c0 00000
[    0.947937] ffc0: d7841ec4 dead4ead ffffffff ffffffff d784ffd0 d784ffd0 d7840
[    0.947937] ffe0: c00a7e94 00000013 00000000 d784fff8 c00a7e94 c00c1c6c e0b19
[    0.947967] Backtrace: 
[    0.947967] [<c0080c20>] (omap4430_phy_power+0x0/0x10c) from [<c039b6e8>] (t)
[    0.947967]  r6:00000001 r5:c081ae10 r4:d781b000 r3:c0080c20
[    0.948028] [<c039b6b0>] (twl6030_phy_init+0x0/0x40) from [<c039b12c>] (musb)
[    0.948059] [<c039aef8>] (musb_otg_notifier_work+0x0/0x238) from [<c00baa14>)
[    0.948059]  r6:d7945000 r5:c0a5cdc0 r4:d78063c0 r3:00000001
[    0.948089] [<c00ba900>] (process_one_work+0x0/0x410) from [<c00bb0b8>] (wor)
[    0.948089] [<c00baf10>] (worker_thread+0x0/0x490) from [<c00c1cf4>] (kthrea)
[    0.948120] [<c00c1c60>] (kthread+0x0/0x98) from [<c00a7e94>] (do_exit+0x0/0)
[    0.948120]  r7:00000013 r6:c00a7e94 r5:c00c1c60 r4:d7841ec4
[    0.948150] Code: e3a0109d e34c0073 eb010200 e89da830 (e1a0c00d) 
[    0.948181] ---[ end trace 65f8ea860415c04f ]---
```

Howere if we do a soft reboot then the system works fine. So are we have found that 
1) Disabling the eye digram correction as below makes the platform to boot correctly.

```
diff --git a/android-3.0/arch/arm/mach-omap2/Kconfig b/android-3.0/arch/arm/mach-        omap2/Kconfig
index 4af6bad..3b2a1a6 100755
--- a/android-3.0/arch/arm/mach-omap2/Kconfig
+++ b/android-3.0/arch/arm/mach-omap2/Kconfig
@@ -459,7 +459,7 @@ config OMAP4_ARM_ERRATA_743622
config OMAP4_HSOTG_ED_CORRECTION
        bool "OMAP 44XX HSOTG Eye diagram correction"
        depends on ARCH_OMAP4
-       default y
+       default n
        help
          Select this option to overrive HSOTG PHY settings in
          order to improve Eye Diagramm. On 4430 CPUs this should
```

2) Also adding delay works. We added delay as follows

```
diff --git a/android-3.0/arch/arm/mach-omap2/omap_phy_internal.c b/android-3.0/arch/arm/mach-omap2/omap_phy_internal.c
index 052678e..bf84b5e 100755
--- a/android-3.0/arch/arm/mach-omap2/omap_phy_internal.c
+++ b/android-3.0/arch/arm/mach-omap2/omap_phy_internal.c
@@ -135,6 +135,8 @@ static void omap44xx_hsotg_ed_correction(void)
         * should be set to value >6
         */

+        ssleep(5);
+
        val = __raw_readl(hsotg_base + 0x2018);
        val |= 0x0F;
        __raw_writel(val, hsotg_base + 0x2018);
```

Note that with either of the two changes we are able to boot the platform correectly.

Also if the USB OTG on the platform is connected to the USB port of a PC then too the system boots correctly.

How can we go about fixing this issue?

Comment: I actually used a fix from http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg51960.html and that seems o slove the issue.

Comment: One more observation is that if the same USB OTG port is connected to the USB port on a PC then too the platform boots up fine.